# Group Chat with persistent members in pidgin

Tags: plugins, pidgin, chat

I want to make a chat-room in `Pidgin`. I know the default way; i.e. using `Add a Chat` from `Buddies` menu. But there are some problems using it!

1. Just the creator can have it in his/her list; so everyone should search and join every single time he/she leaves the chat.
2. People can't set `Auto-Join` and `Persistent` properties to avoid the problem mentioned in 1.

Is there any plugin which I'm unaware of to do this??

Comment: pidgin is just a multi-protocol client. Which protocol are you using to make this chatroom with?

Comment: @LPChip I use XMPP! I found the answer BTW! :D

Comment: Is there any way to create a group like whatsapp in pidgin?

Answer (score 3):

I already found the trick! :-D

Maybe I should have waited some minutes. But I don't delete the question since I think maybe it can help some people in the future.

The trick is once the creator creates the chat, other people should also create a chat with the same name; they will join to the original one and no new room will be made. Then everyone can see this chat in his/her list and can set both `Auto-Join` and `Persistent properties`.